# HP Pavilion dv6000 graphics issue

Tags: graphics-card, windows-registry, hp-pavilion

A few days ago my laptop seized up on me while I was playing a game. When I restarted the computer, it sent me back to 640x480 resolution with 16 colors (clearly a graphical issue). In device manager, it shows an error, stating "Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)" regarding the video card. Upon removing and re-installing the drivers using both Windows Update and my own searching through nvidia's site, it's given me zero results.

For kicks, I ran my antivirus (you never know!) and registry cleaner to see if anything would turn up. The antivirus found nothing, but CCleaner found 27 registry errors all dealing with my video card. What could be the cause of this, and what course of action would you recommend in this situation? Thanks in advance for the help!

OS: Windows 7 Professional
GPU: nvidia GeForce 8400M GS

Answer (score 1):

We have encountered this several times at the shop where I work.  Apparently various HP dv models have a bad solder issue where the solder on the grahpics chips and/or mobo is breaking down due to the heat and the eventual failures occur.  I believe HP finally acknowledge it in certain models.

Go here to see if yours qualifies for extended warranty:

[Warranty Link](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01087277&lc=en&cc=us)

Comment: Looks like mine doesn't qualify for the extended warranty =/

My last-ditch effort will be a reformat in the hopes that it's just a corrupted OS (I never thought I'd find 'just a corrupted OS' to be what I hope is wrong with my computer). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I experience this a multiple times already... it has something to do with the nvidia graphic card.

The first time i resolved this issue was to dismantle my laptop and re-heat the chip (nvidia). It worked. Though I've got some extra screw after I re-assembled my laptop :p

The second time was I reformat my laptop (I don't want to have another screw to put my head)
It worked!!

The third time.. I think back how did it happened.. And I remembered that it only occur after the installation of nvidia updates. So I run system restore and it worked!!! You may also choose not to install the nvidia driver and use the default display driver from win7 (but you cannot use the full function of the nvidia graphic card)

btw my laptop model is HP dv6755, OS = Win7

Answer (score -1):

You can try upgrading the latest BIOS firmware (from HP website) and video driver from nVidia.com. Keep Microsoft generic driver away!

If it's still unresolved, please contact the support because I had similar issues with my Dell XPS M1330. One fine day, it had started showing some blinds in the screen and realized that, I received a bad piece hardware. The support team has helped me to replace it.